# zeroconf implementation on an embedded linux system

Tags: linux, bonjour, zeroconf, avahi

I have an embeeded system that I like to add zeroconf to it. The aim is:

1. Auto assign an IP to itself if there is no dhcp available.
2. It respond to mdns request and identify itself correctly.
3. It responds to dns-ds and broadcast its capability correctly.

Is there any library that can help me on this?

I found Avahi (http://avahi.org/) but it seems there is no development on it for some years. Is it still a good solution?

My device has Linux 2.x on it.

Comment: You mean Linux 2.6.x, right? :)

Answer (score 1):

Avahi seems to be the de-facto standard implementation of Zeroconf for Linux and it is used pretty much everywhere. The last release is from 2012 but this does not mean it is dead -- it may just mean that it is mature and stable enough and there has been no need for additional releases yet.

Comment: Yep, the last Avahi release 0.6.31 is packaged in eg. Debian, Fedora or OpenWRT.